# Read user input from Windows commandline print only from second letter - Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, user-input, system.in

When I run below lines in Windows command line it does not take the first letter. If I enter `22` it prints only `'2'`

```
private static String  readInput() {
    try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         input = br.readLine();
         System.out.println("input "+input);

   } catch (Exception ioe) {
      System.out.println("Error trying to read your input!");
      ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: share other part of your code

Comment: In eclipse this works fine. But in DOS it doesn't work

Comment: are you sure that Eclipse version and DOS version are the same?

Comment: Sorry I'm lost what is it? I build the jar file and use the command >java -jar MyProg.jar then it call my main class and that class tries to get the user input

Comment: @Homayoun Afshari This is the code. From the main method its calling this method to take the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println("input "+input);
    }
```

Comment: Program doesn't continue. Its continues within the while. EX:
Enter the service number : 1
input
input
input

Answer (score 0):

try like this!

```
private static String  readInput() {
try {
     DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
     input = in.readLine();
     System.out.println("input "+input);
     return input;
   } catch (Exception ioe) {
      System.out.println("Error trying to read your input!");
      ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. Its not relate to scanner or BufferedReader. All works fine.
One of my another back end thread is reading `System.in.read();`. That's why I always missed first input. Sorry for confusing all of you.